# Shortest unique combination of at least three characters for each string in list

Tags: python, combinatorics

I want to find the shortest unique combination of characters for each element in a list of strings. Each combination should consist of the string's first character and its two rarest characters at least (more if necessary) and order matters. If a character appears more than once in one string, it should get more weight.

Consider the following example:

```
liste = ["apple", "pear", "banana", "xylophone", "bear", "banunu"]
combinations = ["apl", "per", "ban", "xyh", "ber", "bnu"
```

for `apple`, both `p` and `e` appear 4 times overall, but since `p` appears twice in `apple`, it should be used in the combination.

What is the most efficient way to write this logic in python?

Comment: *"for apple, both p and e appear 4 times overall,..."* I didn't get it. How do they appear 4 times?

Comment: In all strings together, both `p` and `e` occur 4 times in total. The total number of occurrences of a character is what determines its rarity and whether it should be included in the combination. In case of a tie, like here, preference should be given to the character that appears more than once in the string (if any).

Comment: Why `'l'` instead of `'h'` in xylophone?

Comment: My mistake, thanks. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import heapq

from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter


def combination(word, n, counts):
    word_count = Counter(word)
    elements = []
    seen = set()
    for i, c in enumerate(word[1:]):
        if c not in seen:
            elements.append((-1 * counts[c], word_count[c], i, c))
            seen.add(c)
    top = heapq.nlargest(n, elements)
    characters = map(itemgetter(3), top)

    return word[0] + ''.join(sorted(characters, key=lambda x: word.index(x)))


lst = ["apple", "pear", "banana", "xylophone", "bear", "banunu"]

counts = Counter(''.join(lst))

result = [combination(w, 2, counts) for w in lst]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['apl', 'per', 'ban', 'xyh', 'ber', 'bnu']
```

The idea is to create a tuple of the priority criterias representing each *unique* letter. So `elements` is a list containing tuples represeting:

1. `counts[c]`: The overall count (as you want the rarest multiply by -1)
2. `word_count[c]`: The specific count of the letter in the word
3. `i`: represents the firs position of the letter
4. `c`: the letter itself.

Once you create the list `elements` with:

```
elements = []
seen = set()
for i, c in enumerate(word[1:]):
    if c not in seen:
        elements.append((-1 * counts[c], word_count[c], i, c))
        seen.add(c)
```

Note that as the characters must be unique we use a set (`seen`) to guarantee uniqueness. Finally you use [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to get the top `n` elements according to the above criterias.

Comment: Zero explanation on how this works, or what heapq is

Comment: That seems like exactly what I was looking for! Could you elaborate a bit on `elements.append((-1 * counts[c], word_count[c], i, c))` and what `heapq.nlargest(n, elements)` does?

Comment: @iuvbio Updated the answer!